# Robocopy using /copyall generates error 3- related to security?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I have a simple .bat file that copies a mapped network folder to a local external drive (NTSF). This was working perfectly, but there was a SNAFU with my domain profile and upon rebuilding my profile it seems I have lost the right to copy files from the server using this code:

```
    Robocopy \\###.###.##.###\ShareFile "G:\Folder\File_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%" /e /z /np /copyall /R:5 /R:2
```

Error 3 90x00000003) Accessing Source Directory Y:\ 
The system cannot find the path specified.

I know the COPYALL requires full privileges, and I need this info copied. I am a local admin, admin on the server, and a Domain admin... how can I not have the security rights?

Comment: Can you open a cmd prompt and execute dir y:\ with no errors?

Comment: Yup, no problem. And as mentioned below, changing to full UNC path causes same error.

Comment: if you remove `/copyall` does it actually go ahead with the copy?  I'm trying to ascertain if it's robocopy alone or another issue that is contributing.  The error says `The system cannot find the path specified.` which generally means the server is not available.

Comment: Huh, removing /copyall is still giving me the same error. I have the server mapped and can access files on it. I can cmd dir and access the files. What am I missing?

Comment: Holy crap, I had a typo in the full UNC path!!! Ok full UNC path was the trick!! THanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your network drive remapped?

I would reccomend using the full UNC path instead of a drive letter.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is mapped, get the same error with UNC path. Edited above code.